# Future Position for linearly moving object unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-physics

An object is linearly moving forward with Starting Speed(SP) of 8 and its acceleration is 0.02f per second. `SP is curSpeed= minSpeed`
(1) `minSpeed= 8`
(2) `maxSpeed=20`
(3) `curSpeed += acceleration * Time.deltaTime` - until reach to maxSpeed
Where the object will be after 10, 15, or 30 seconds?
I need to spawn an object in advance from the current player position to its future position after few seconds to sync the gameplay. Let's say the player is at zero and after ten seconds is distance will 90, I will spawn the object at 90 in advance for the player to catch. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved by math, but I have another idea. Make an empty gameobject as child of your moving object. Move it in the direction of movement by desired distance. Make a reference to this gameobject's transform in script with

```
public Transform spawnPoint
```

And assign it in inspector. Now you can spawn your objects in advance at `spawnPoint.position` no matter of speed or time, it will be at the same distance from your player.

Math solution:
First of all, you need to store start position to a Vector3. Let's call it `startPos`. Then we need a movement direction vector. For example (but it depends on your movement)

```
Vector3 direction = Vector3.forward;
```

Then you are talking about 2 types of movement: accelerating and linear.

Let's calculate time for acceleration:

```
float aTime = (maxSpeed - minSpeed)/acceleration;
```

Let's calculate the position where acceleration ends:

```
Vector3 aEndPos = startPos + direction * (minSpeed * aTime + acceleration * Mathf.Pow(aTime, 2) / 2f);
```

Now we can write method for calculating distance:

```
Vector3 GetDistance(float time)
{
  Vector3 direction = Vector3.forward;
  float aTime = (maxSpeed - minSpeed)/acceleration;
  Vector3 aEndPos = startPos + direction * (minSpeed * aTime + acceleration * Mathf.Pow(aTime, 2) / 2f);

  if (time <= aTime) //if we are in accelerating movement
  {
      return startPos + direction * (minSpeed * time + acceleration * Mathf.Pow(time, 2) / 2f);
  } 
  else // we are in linear
  {
      return aEndPos + direction * maxSpeed * (time - aTime)
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. It may work in a few cases like if need to spawn a few meters away from the player like ( 5, 10, 20 ). Actually  I need to sync spawning with music beats. For example, I have an audio 120sec long, in which beats occur at (2.2), (8.2),(9.93),(11.2),(11.5) and so on. Here is the graph and mathematical solution I'm looking into https://youtu.be/0YsudDWJlf8